# BitTorrent Sync: syncing home folder

Tags: permissions, sync, bittorrent

I would like to use BitTorrent Sync to sync either the home folder or various subfolders, such as Desktop, Documents, Pictures across two machines running Ubuntu (versions 14.04 and 15.04). I'm having a hard time with permissions--when I try to sync the Desktop folder for example, I get a warning that btsync doesn't have permission to write to selected folder.

How should I install btsync so that this issue doesn't arise? I've tried to do it by installing btsync both as the default user option, root, and as my own username, to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried to create a dummy folder and giving full access rights to that folder, like chmod -R 777 and see does it work at all or maybe there is some problem with you folder path set in btsync?

Comment: I did attempt to change the permissions manually, although not for a dummy folder, I had tried it for the Desktop folder that I was interested in syncing.